# Where do I find the list of weapons referenced in this Netherlands weapon law?

Tags: weapons, netherlands

I am reading the [wet wapens en munitie](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0008804/2013-01-01), which is the Dutch law concerning possession of weapons and ammunition.

In this law there is frequent referrence to "bij regeling van Onze Minister aangewezen voorwerpen die geschikt zijn om daarmee personen ernstig lichamelijk letsel toe te brengen" (approxiately: *objects designated by the OM as suitable for causing serious physical injury to people*).

Is there any place where I can find a comprehensive list of objects marked as such, or does the minister simply decide on a case by case basis whether the object carried by a person is or is not a weapon?

Comment: I would assume that one would look at the regulations issued by the relevant ministry of the Dutch government, but I don't know any resources for obtaining codified Dutch regulations, although I would be almost certain that they exist.

Answer (score 2):

The secondary legislation related to this law is the [Regeling wapens en munitie](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0008800/2019-10-11); as far as I can see, it does not contain a definition for category IV.6, the category that matches the particular description you mention, but it does make reference to that article in the preamble.

In general, the law itself delegates the authority to define weapons that match this category to the Minister of Justice and Security; this would generally be implemented as a piece of secondary legislation, a ministerial order (ministeriële regeling). It would not be ruled on on a case by case basis.